# Using KineticJS with ScriptSharp

Tags: kineticjs, script#

i am currently porting an Silverlight Project to HTML/Javascript.

After some research i decideed to use ScriptSharp instead of Javascript and using KineticJS as UI Layer.

But it seems ScriptSharp doesnt support the KineticJS Api atm.
I guess it needed to be implemented here: 
https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/src/Libraries

The same Problem exists in the TypeScript domain:
Here i have found the typed Libaries for KineticJS.
http://kineticjstypescript.codeplex.com/

The question is now, if its possible in an easy way to get a CLR for KineticJS ?
At leased there should be a possibility to convert the existsing TypeScript Metadata Project to a ScriptSharp Project ??

Comment: KineticJS is extremely "object oriented" even though there are no classes/objects in javascript.  It shouldn't be much effort to define some Interfaces that wrap the Kinetic "objects".  Don't be afraid of the overly-large Kinetic.com documents pages.  In practice, there are maybe a dozen often used Kinetic objects. Each object has a small "sane" amount of methods used in practice. Off-topic, but I'm an old fan of Silverlight and while I'm still in the Microsoft camp, it really is a shame the way they let it "die on the vine".

Comment: thanks for your answer, yeah i am a big silverlight fan as well, but finally i have to rewrite the UI so it can run on mobile devices. Its a shame, SL is so much better than HTML/Javascript...
actually what u have said is some kind of plan C. Plan B is to write an own translator from Typescript definition to ScriptSharp definition. Makes more sense for me...

Comment: It would be nice to see that library stubbed out for S#. Let me know if you need help getting started.

Comment: currently i have gone away from the idea to port it to HTML. I will port to MonoGame, it runs on many plattforms, and i guess porting is much easier, and i hope it will perform even better. so i wont make any effort to marke a Script# CLR for KineticJS.